# Is there a way to select the current month column in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, subquery

I am trying to select multiple columns from a table. One being a column that contains "MAY_A" (current month actuals). The months are separated into multiple columns.

The table looks as below

```
ORG    ORG2    APR_A_CNT    MAY_A_CNT    ............
--------------------------------------------------------------
a      def    4             6
b      def    6             8
.      .      .             .  
.      .      .             .
.      .      .             .
```

What I have tried is below. I selected the needed column name (MAY_A) from the schema. Just can't seem to get the SELECT to take it as a column name in the table I want.

```
SELECT  ORG, ORG2, (SELECT  COLUMN_NAME
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'SUMMARY'
            AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%' + UPPER(CONVERT(char(3), GETDATE(),0)) + '_A%')
FROM [DB].[dbo].[SUMMARY]
```

What I current have outputs:

```
ORG    ORG2    (no column name)
--------------------------------
a      def     NULL   
b      def     NULL
.      .       .           
.      .       .
.      .       .
```

What I want is:

```
ORG    ORG2    MAY_A_CNT
--------------------------
a      def     6
b      def     8
.      .       .           
.      .       .
.      .       .
```

Comment: dynamic SQL is needed here..., build the sql string, then execute

Comment: I've built the string. Having trouble implementing it into my code.

Comment: test sub-select also, looks like this is not returning data either

Comment: I am not sure how to do that. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is why table design like this is a bad idea. Dynamic information should be in cell contents, not table or column names.

Comment: Really consider normalizing this wide format table to long format. Use of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` in business logic is not recommended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CASE` to select the column you want.

```
SELECT ORG, ORG2,
    CASE MONTH(GETDATE())
        WHEN 1 THEN JAN_A_CNT
        WHEN 2 THEN FEB_A_CNT
        WHEN 3 THEN MAR_A_CNT
        ...
        WHEN 12 THEN DEC_A_CNT
    END AS CUT_MONTH_CNT
FROM [DB].[dbo].[SUMMARY]
```